# Initials of email looks strange on Wordpress Website

Tags: theme-customizer

My website based on wordpress platform is acting strange. To be noted, that i bought the theme, and implemented it, I am not an expert developer.

The major thing I am facing is the email format, like when you visit the contact page of my website it is showing the email as "Thisisan@Gmail.Com" which is wrong, as it should show it like "thisisan@gmail.com" which is the standard format.

Here is the picture;

[image: Wordpress email issue]

Is there any tweet I can make it show all small letters?

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen on the other fields too?

My guess would be to check the CSS, there will likely be a `text-transform: capitalize` property which makes them appear capitalized.

You can get rid of the property as a whole, or remove the input selector from the CSS.

If you want it to just impact this field, then depending on the theme setup, you may be able to find which theme file has this form and add in a manual `style="text-transform: none;"` to it.

If it is CSS, it may not be actually impacting the data but just how it's presented (just a visual change).

If it's not CSS, it might be JS.

Comment: I tried removing input[type=email] from the selector but I didn't work. Can you tell me if I can find text-transform: capitalize?

Comment: There may be more. Have you checked no other selectors are being applied? Use Chrome's inspect tool to check what CSS properties are applied to that specific element.

Comment: I am facing this problem on just two pages only "Contact Us" and "Donate via PayPal